# How to remove console window on the start?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake

On the app start i have a console window, so how not to show it?
(Without Using WinMain! Because its parameters don't match to QApp)

My main.cpp code is:

```
int main(int _nArgCount, char * _pArgValues[]) {

    QApplication app(_nArgCount, _pArgValues);          

    //QMLblock
    QString strQmlPath = "qrc:qml/main.qml";
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl(strQmlPath));
    if (component.status() == QQmlComponent::Error) {
        qDebug()<<"Error:"<<component.errorString();
        return app.exec();
    }

    Gui gui(component);
    gui.recreateGui();

    //state machine block
    QStateMachine machine;
```

....
....
....

```
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: How does your `.pro` file look like? Try to remove the console explicitly with `CONFIG -= console` then rerun qmake and build again.

Comment: I use cmake, and Visual studio

Comment: The problem is solved! by adding #pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup") in main.cpp! i'll make it as an answer, after timeout allows me )

Comment: Ok, if you use CMake, you have to add `WIN32` in the `add_executable` call: e.g. `add_executable(MyApp WIN32 ${MyApp_SOURCES}). Now you don't have to add this pragma.

Comment: @thomas_b i tryed it, but got few link errors, so still pragma )